# How to power this pressure sensor?

Tags: sensor, wiring, pressure

So guys, I have a pressure sensor and I want to measure the pressure on a water tube.
The things is, I can't find ANYTHING about it on the internet, not a single datasheet.
It's only 3 wires, will anyone take a shot?
Thanks a lot.
[image: pic]

3 pics here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHsVr.jpg

Comment: It says right on the module. RIGHT ON THE MODULE! Almost all of the information is there!

Comment: Logic says red: +, black -, white signal.

Answer (score 2):

Vcc = +24V and the senor output is 4 to 20mA. 4mA is probably 0 PSIG or PSI and 200 PSI is 20mA. Black is probably ground, Red is probably VCC and white is probably signal. Ohm it out

Comment: I thought your comment was enough, but nice one. I would have recommended a voltage measurement for the output signal, so why did you say 'Ohm it out'?

Comment: Could also be a passive sensor, so the loop-current is the actual measured value and the white cable is used for something else.

Comment: I said ohm it out because sometimes you can tell what kind of sensor it is, or if you use the diode mode if you have it. It might be something as simple as a BJT and a sensor.